# Invalidate cache in a Apache server to use GatsbyJS

Tags: reactjs, apache, .htaccess, gatsby

I am trying to deploy my site with is generated by Gatsby in a Apache server. As per [Gatsby docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/caching/#page-data) the cache control should be set like this for `public/page-data`

> The cache-control header should be cache-control: public, max-age=0,
> must-revalidate1

So I added a `.htaccess` file in `public/page-data` folder. For some reason the files are still cached and getting error with http code `409` conflict.

This is the `.htaccess` files contents.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css|php|json)>
FileETag None
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Is there any way to invalidate cache for `/public/page-data`

**Update**

The page in which I am getting 409 is this

```
import React from 'react';
import PageContent from '../components/UI/PageContents';
import Layout from '../components/layout';
import SEO from '../components/seo';

const Contact = () => (
  <Layout innerPage="nk-contact" headerText="Contact us">
    <SEO title="Contact us" />
    <PageContent>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <section className="mb-2">
            <h2 data-aos="fade-right">Contact us at</h2>
            {[
              '+91 1111111',
              '+91 2222222',
              '+91 2222222',
              '+91 2222222',
            ].map((number, index) => (
              <span key={`call-${index}`}>
                <a href={`tel:${number}`}>{number}</a>
                <br />
              </span>
            ))}

            <div className="py-1 mb-4">
              <h3 className="pt-3 pb-1 d-block">Email</h3>
              
              
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <section className="mb-1">
            <h3 data-aos="fade-right">Our Timing</h3>
            <p>Office timings: 9.00 am - 6.00 pm.</p>
          </section>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <h3 data-aos="fade-left" className="mb-3">
        Our Sales address
      </h3>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-6">
          <address>
            <strong> xxxxx</strong>
            <br />
            xxxxx
          </address>
        </div>
      </div>
    </PageContent>
  </Layout>
);

export default Contact;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The public folder is redone in every compilation of code (`gatsby build`) so probably, your `.htaccess` is being deleted in each code deployment.

Said that, you have at least 2 approaches:

- Using some plugin like [`gatsby-plugin-htaccess`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-htaccess/)
- Create the `.htaccess` in the [static folder](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/images-and-media/static-folder/). The static folder, placed in the root of your project, is being transpiled with the same internal structure (and without Gatsby's treatment or processing by its transformers) to the /public, so if your place there a `/static/.htaccess` (or `/static/page-data/.htaccess` if you want) will be present in the public folder once compiled.

Comment: Hmm... the fact that it's the contact page, which will send a request to the server and a 409 issue (that is a conflict) seems related to the fetch method. Take a look at it or share that page code

Comment: The page dont have any fetch. Its just a simple jsk page. I have update the question with page source

Comment: Where number comes from?